# Unable to perform any queries with Prisma and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, prisma

I'm starting a new Next.js project and trying, and failing, to integrate my application with a local running instance of mongod (MongoDBCompass works fine). Below is a simple API endpoint to test a findMany() invocation.

In `/src/pages/api/db-actions.ts`:

```js
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";


export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  console.log("Finding users...")
  const users = await db.user.findMany()
  
  console.log("Done", users)

  return res.status(200).json({users: users})
}
```

After tapping the endpoint I get the following error:

```
 ⨯ PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.user.findMany()` invocation:


Raw query failed. Code: `unknown`. Message: `Kind: Command failed: Error code 73 (InvalidNamespace): Invalid namespace specified '.User', labels: {}`
    at In.handleRequestError (C:\dev\forenzix-migration-2\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:122:6854)
    at In.handleAndLogRequestError (C:\dev\forenzix-migration-2\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:122:6188)
    at In.request (C:\dev\forenzix-migration-2\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:122:5896)
    at async l (C:\dev\forenzix-migration-2\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:127:10871)
    at async handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/pages/api/db-actions.ts:9:19)
    at async K (C:\dev\forenzix-migration-2\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\pages-api.runtime.dev.js:21:2946)
    at async U.render (C:\dev\forenzix-migration-2\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\pages-api.runtime.dev.js:21:3827)
    at async DevServer.runApi (C:\dev\forenzix-migration-2\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:556:9)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (C:\dev\forenzix-migration-2\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:268:37)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\dev\forenzix-migration-2\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:807:17)
    at async C:\dev\forenzix-migration-2\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:331:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\dev\forenzix-migration-2\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:151:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\dev\forenzix-migration-2\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:328:24)
    at async invokeRender (C:\dev\forenzix-migration-2\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:163:21)
    at async handleRequest (C:\dev\forenzix-migration-2\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:342:24) {
  code: 'P2010',
  clientVersion: '5.11.0',
  meta: {
    modelName: 'User',
    code: 'unknown',
    message: "Kind: Command failed: Error code 73 (InvalidNamespace): Invalid namespace specified '.User', labels: {}"
  },
  page: '/api/db-actions'
}
```

I'm not sure what's invalid about the namespace it's using. I've made the User collection under 'test' through Compass but to no avail.

Here is the schema file I'm using. Note that this file was actually generated by prisma after running `npx prisma db pull`.

In `/prisma/schema.prisma`

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id          String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name        String @unique    // Added by me
  passhash    String            // Added by me
}
```

And my .env file:

```
DATABASE_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/test
```

Versions of my installations:

```
Node: v18.18.8
Next.js: 14.1.0
Prisma (& Client): 5.11.0
MongoDB: 7.0.6
```

I've tried many different things over the past couple of days and I'm finally stumped. Do let me know if I've missed out any key details.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `lib/db` look like? How do you instantiate `PrismaClient`?

Comment: @PerttuHaliseva My lib/db file looks almost identical to the boilerplate code from [this page](https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-prisma-postgres#step-4.-install-and-generate-prisma-client). In the end all I had to do was make one manual insert into the mongoDB database and it worked. Still not sure why it didn't work from the outset but it's behind me now. Thanks for the help :)